# Best statistical practise to take into account batch effects and biological variation

Tags: r, batch-normalization

I've the following dataframe: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IxwI52nIdolzL9wzbxiDmu5NGR5eoukX/view?usp=sharing

I'm wondering the best statistical analysis to investigate the relationship with the size of the colony perimeters and bacterial strains mixed with treatment variation.

The hypthesis being that the perimeter of gamma strain is greater than alpha or beta strain in the presence of a chemoatttractant 0 mM succinate, 1 mM succinate and 10 mM succinate. I want to take into account any batch effect across experiments, along with random effects from bacterial variation. I initally just applied boxplots and investigated significant with wilcox rank tests, however it didn't take into account any batch effects or random variation.

Any advice on any kind of transformation i could, apply which would take into effect this. Or should i be looking at it more from a linear mixed model perspective ?

If i run the ComBat function for example i consistently get this error: Error in dat[, batch == batch_level] :
(subscript) logical subscript too long

Comment: Can you give the code you're using for ComBat (also provide the link to ComBat for those who don't know)? My guess is that you're R1 batch is too small. Also to clarify, in the context of these models, bacterial variation isn't "random", it's your effect of interest!

Comment: Hi @DavidB sure. Sorry i tried removing it as well and still had the same effect. This is ComBat for everyone (https://rdrr.io/bioc/sva/man/ComBat.html).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FC7Lt1Gkun_ycOlFQZb31-2jR0Qc8OgI/view?usp=sharing Code Snippet.  What i'm interesting in is "correcting" any variability within batches. I'm investigating the perimeter (cm) of bacterial colonies. The biological sample column contains numbers refering to individial strain cultures i used. For example strain Alpha and strain Beta being 1 and 2, with "1 and 2" being a mixture of strain Alpha and Beta denoted as Gamma on the Bacteria column.

Comment: What is the "biological samples" column? Does it make sense to have it be a factor?

Comment: @DavidB 
Okay, sorry it can be a little confusing, here is an image of an explanation. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FSrMlIuEySm1wJXu8UCjBjIM16WL0vF9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the non-stats question: The error you're seeing is because ComBat is designed for experiments with *multiple* outcomes. You only have one (perimeter), so it's throwing an error at a step when it expects a matrix, but all it's seeing is a vector.

Now the stats bit: A mixed effect model is typically how one would ask this question. Now, the fact that you are using ComBat suggests that you expect that strains will differ in more than just their means (i.e., that there's heteroskedasticity). If this is a concern, you could use a [double-hglm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dhglm/) to adjust to strain differences in variance as well.

An example of how to test your question with a standard mixed effect model:

```
    library(lmerTest)
     mod1=lmer(Perimeter..cm. ~ Treatment + (1|Biological.samples),data=p.data)
     anova(mod1)
    Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
              Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
    Treatment 506.58  253.29     2 92.685   27.85 3.377e-10 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
     
summary(mod1)
    Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
    Formula: Perimeter..cm. ~ Treatment + (1 | Biological.samples)
       Data: p.data
    
    REML criterion at convergence: 824.1
    
    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -2.3275 -0.5361 -0.1112  0.3942  3.3652 

Random effects:
 Groups             Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Biological.samples (Intercept) 22.085   4.699   
 Residual                        9.095   3.016   
Number of obs: 144, groups:  Biological.samples, 50

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                6.2674     0.7978 74.1016   7.856 2.41e-11 ***
Treatment1 mM succinate    3.5914     0.6237 92.6853   5.758 1.10e-07 ***
Treatment10 mM succinate   4.3605     0.6237 92.6853   6.991 4.13e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Tr1mMs
Trtmnt1mMsc -0.391       
Trtmnt10mMs -0.391  0.500
```

**Edit** Something similar with `dhglm`, comparing the Alpha and Beta bacteria:

```
library(dhglm)

p.data.temp = p.data %>% dplyr::filter(ï..Bacteria == "Alpha"  | ï..Bacteria == "Beta")

# typical mixed effect model 
model_mu<-DHGLMMODELING(Model="mean",
                        LinPred=Perimeter..cm.~ ï..Bacteria +(1|Batch.No.))

# model variance
model_phi<-DHGLMMODELING(Model="dispersion", 
                         LinPred=phi~ ï..Bacteria +(1|Batch.No.),RandDist="gaussian")

#put it together
res_dhglm1<-dhglmfit(RespDist="gamma",DataMain=p.data.temp,
                     MeanModel=model_mu,DispersionModel=model_phi)

Distribution of Main Response :  
                         "gamma" 
[1] "Estimates from the model(mu)"
Perimeter..cm. ~ ï..Bacteria + (1 | Batch.No.)
[1] "identity"
                Estimate Std. Error t-value
(Intercept)       11.318     1.0068  11.242
ï..BacteriaBeta   -7.348     0.9539  -7.703
[1] "Estimates for logarithm of lambda=var(u_mu)"
[1] "gaussian"
          Estimate Std. Error t-value
Batch.No.   0.5491     0.5473   1.003
[1] "Estimates from the model(phi)"
phi ~ ï..Bacteria + (1 | Batch.No.)
[1] "log"
                Estimate Std. Error t-value
(Intercept)      -1.5263     0.2534  -6.023
ï..BacteriaBeta  -0.6285     0.2997  -2.097
[1] "Estimates for logarithm of var(u_phi)"
          Estimate Std. Error t-value
Batch.No.   -1.396     0.8561  -1.631
[1] "========== Likelihood Function Values and Condition AIC =========="
                                                        [,1]
-2ML (-2 p_v(mu),v(phi) (h))          :            294.33754
-2RL (-2 p_beta(mu),v(mu),beta(phi),v(phi) (h)) :  292.21448
cAIC                           :                   290.18455
Scaled Deviance                :                    51.32276
df                             :                    51.32276
```

These results suggest an effect of bacteria, and you could repeat the analysis without the Bacteria variable and use the ratio of the likelihoods to compute a p-value (or compare the cAIC). You can also use a simpler model for the variance (`model_phi<-DHGLMMODELING(Model="dispersion")`) to see whether accounting for differences in variance between batches really matters (it doesn't seem to in this case).

Comment: Hi @DavidB thank you, i'll look into a "double-hglm". That's kinda the issue. In terms of i want to remove batch effects to use ComBat to standardise the perimeter values to account for this. I'd then effectively just compare Alpha to Beta or Alpha to Gamma across the three treatments in a seperate Wilcox rank test (https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/wilcoxon-test-in-r/) and portray this on a box-plot. If I also have the areas for the colonies as well. Would that allow the ComBat function to work ?

Comment: I mean crudely could this also work ? # Create a new column with the mean perimeter value for each batch
df$batch_mean <- tapply(df$Perimeter, df$Batch, mean)[as.character(df$Batch)]
# Create a new column with the standard deviation of the perimeter values for each batch
df$batch_sd <- tapply(df$Perimeter, df$Batch, sd)[as.character(df$Batch)]
# Create a new column with the Z-score for each perimeter value based on its batch mean and standard deviation
df$Perimeter_Z <- (df$Perimeter - df$batch_mean) / df$batch_sd
df$PerimeterRange<- decostand(df$Perimeter_Z, "range")

Comment: What you're describing - normalizing within batch - is kind of a poor man's mixed model. The problem is that it depends on the sample size of each batch to be accurate, which they may not be. A mixed model uses partial pooling across batches, so it will tend to be more accurate. Why do you want to use a non-paramteric test if you're already correcting for differences in means *and* variances?

Comment: Hi @DavidB thank you so much. I guess i'm just a little confused myself about how to make this double-hglm model fit in R. If i want to do a comparison between say the perimeters of strain Alpha and Beta how would i do it ?

Comment: I updated my answer with example code.

Comment: Thank you, with Bacteria i have an cAIC of 290.18455 and without  Bacteria i have an cAIC of 350.65686. So rudimentarily with the inclusion of Bacteria the cAIC is "better". I understand this line of research to an extent. But what i'm really wanting to achieve is testing for example is the perimeter of Alpha or Gamma greater in the presence of an attractant 0mM succ vs. 1 mM succ for example, when taking into account for batch effects (these are scans of fluorescence).

Comment: Effictively, i had these kind of results and plots made of the different strains and outliers removed and comparions. However, i was doing some more work and realised that i should take into account any batch effects. This was initially calculated as you can see in the final figure, by standardising everything by the Alpha strain. For example if it was 7 cm it would be 7/7cm = 1, but the corresponding Beta strain for example would be 4/7cm= 0.57.     https://drive.google.com/file/d/113-u7nVtAuCyVpBUU-cyW_mwvJn4mHAI/view?usp=sharing I would just like to correct these plots for batch effects.

Comment: Ok, so: 1) You're describing an interaction (bacteria x treatment). So you would do the same thing with cAIC, but with and without the interaction term. 2) ratios are hardly ever a good way to standardize things, because they behave in unexpected way (they aren't normal, often highly skewed, *more* likely to have different variances);

Comment: And 3) if you think batch effects just effect the mean - and so far, other than your use of ComBat, it sounds like you think that's the case - then you can use a mixed effect model to run a regression controlling for batch as a random effect. Take the residuals of that model, and voila, corrected for batch.

Comment: I couldn't get ComBot to work on the perimeters and the batches.

Comment: Ok so I ran this and it suggests that the perimeter is effected by random batch effects. Is it possible to use this information to transform the perimeter value, so that random batch effects are removed ? 

refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
Data: Alpha
Models:
mod2: Perimeter ~ Treatment
mod1: Perimeter ~ Treatment + (1 | Batch)
     npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
mod2    4 188.53 194.27 -90.266   180.53                         
mod1    5 179.43 186.60 -84.715   169.43 11.101  1  0.0008627 ***

Comment: 1) Right, combat requires a bunch of variables to work. 2) You can run Perimeter ~ 1+ (1 | Batch) and take the residuals. BUT, this is less ideal than running the full analysis as a mixed model. If you want to adjust for the alpha strain, instead of taking a ratio you should include it as a covariate.

Comment: Hi @DavidB thank you so much, for this help. Here is an attempt at crudely adjusting the the perimeters for random batch effects. Thoughts on how to improve it ? I'm not sure what the StackExchange equivalent of a beer is but thank you. 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Io4tmQfUZ3e1JWO-NlpfDxwGR-9j1pxn/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100198403677827098540&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: No beer necessary, just accept the answer! You're adjusting for batch within each bacteria, and then ALSO adjusting for differences between bacteria - is that what you want? But again - this is all just equivalent to a mixed effect model i.e., `mod_all<-lmer(Perimeter ~ Treatment  + Bacteria + (1|Batch),data = colony)`

Comment: Thank you, am i corrrect in thinking then @DavidB if i run: mod_all<-lmer(Perimeter ~ Treatment  + Bacteria + (1|Batch),data = colony) can i take the residuals to adj. the perimeter like i have done ? As a crude adjustment ?

Comment: Is there anywhere cite in literature, that I can  reference saying i can do this: 
mod_all_per.adj<-lmer(Perimeter ~ 1+(1|Batch),data = colony)
perm.batch.m.summary<-summary(mod_all_per.adj)
colony.new<-as.data.frame(perm.batch.m.summary$residuals) @DavidB

Comment: A core assumption of mixed effect models is that residuals are i.i.d, so any introductory text should do. You could also do a mixed model with the *residuals* to show that they are now unrelated to batch.

Comment: i decided to go with you original suggestion, statistical help and advice. It's been a while since my MSc. Thanks (Cyber Beer)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer ;) (cyber beer can be purchased with internet points)